# ElementTree (xml.etree) Parsing XML

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing

Having trouble parsing this xml. Can anyone enlighten me on how it should be done?

Here is what I have tried.

**XML (test.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<element xmlns="http://yoursite.com/">
    <hello>
        <world>1</world>
        <world>2</world>
        <world>3</world>
        <world>4</world>
    </hello>
</element>
```

**PYTHON**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open("test.xml",'r') as f:
    tree = ET.parse(f)

for node in tree.findall('.//element/hello/world'):
    print node.text
```

When I run this python I get absolutely nothing. Please be kind, as I imagine this should be incredibly simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these tags live under a namespace (`xmlns="http://yoursite.com/"`). So you need either prefix the search with this namespace or create a alias mapping, e.g.:

```
>>> ns = {'myns': 'http://yoursite.com/'}
>>> for node in tree.findall(('./myns:hello/myns:world'), ns):
...     print(node.text)
1
2
3
4
```

Note: `.` is your root node so `myns:element` would not find anything (you have no `element` under your root).

The search without the alias would look like:

```
for node in tree.findall(('./{http://yoursite.com/}hello/{http://yoursite.com/}world')):
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. That probably would have taken much longer than I would have liked to figure out.